# Como pasar variables de string a JObject C# - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, jsonobject, async-await

Buen día, necesito asignar variables a JObjet:

```
     JObject json = JObject.Parse(@"{
    RequestData: {
      AccountCredential: {
        AccountLink: 'dFyRCVYNM0aGb1LSR/0B8e+eSVr1Zf1xj9YHmMVoiZWk28XtWEyIxEbGXnr1EdvS+QBPzjweau7tbf5QlDv97IQ2jwfUB=='
      },
      AccountNumber: '000011887755',
      BookingDateStart: '2022-07',
      BookingDateEnd: '2022-07'
    },
    CallbackUrl: 'https://my-api.my-business.com/api/open-data-response'
  }");
```

Deseo pasar valores al AccountLink, al AccountNumber,BookingDateStart, BookingDateEnd.
Si se fija, puse los valores en duro, pero estos cambian, en donde debo usarlo pasando los parametros.

He tratado de usar el JsonSerializerOptions, pero me sale error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json. Deseo poder usarlo en una tarea asincronica.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, se le agradece su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: En una cadena con formato JSON, todos los atributos o propiedades deben estar encerrados en comillas dobles. Siendo que es una cadena de texto que se delimita con comillas dobles para iniciar y finalizar, debes escapar las comillas de los atributos, por ejemplo: `"{ \"Usuario\": \"valor\" }"`. Ajusta la cadena que estás creando para que cumpla con la [especificacion de JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Answer (score 0):

Este fragmento de código es un ejemplo para serializar en formato JSON. Solo adáptalo a tu situación.

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace SerializeWriteIndented
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var weatherForecast = new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Parse("2019-08-01"),
                TemperatureCelsius = 25,
                Summary = "Hot"
            };

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
            string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast, options);

            Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
        }
    }
}

// output:
//{
//  "Date": "2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00",
//  "TemperatureCelsius": 25,
//  "Summary": "Hot"
//}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero me da error al utilizar el JsonSerializerOptions, me dice  Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json